# jquery form when server failed

Tags: jqueryform

I using jquery form plugin from malsup http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

In the http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started example, how do I modify the code to return error message when server failed, eg return server code 500?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call ajaxForm you can pass it an options parameter like that for $.ajax

So set the error option to a callback function like

```
$('#myFormId').ajaxForm(
    {
        success: function(){
            alert("No error!");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("An error has occured");
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: No problem :)
Please upvote if it helped you
Glad to be of service